# matlab increase performance of subs in loops

Tags: matlab

I have something like this. Where RC.p14 is some function dependent on some parameters.

```
        t=ogj.a:ogj.s:ogj.b;
        lk1 = zeros(1,length(t));

        f1=RC.lkPrepare(@RC.p14,l1);

        for i=1:length(t)
            lk1(i)=RC.lk(@RC.p14,l1,t(i),f1);
        end            
    end

    function res=lk(p,l,t,f)           
        res=subs(f, 'z', t)/p(l,t);
    end

   function res=lkPrepare(p,l)
        syms z
        res=diff(1-p(l,z));            
    end
```

But subs in loop took too much time. And is there a way to prepare function for the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `subs` allow substitute several values (e.g. vector or matrix) at single call. In your case, you can do substitution without loop:

```
    t=ogj.a:ogj.s:ogj.b;

    f1=RC.lkPrepare(@RC.p14,l1);

    lk1=RC.lk(@RC.p14,l1,t,f1);
end

function res=lk(p,l,t,f)
    syms z   
    res=subs(f, z, t)./subs(p(l,z), z, t);
end
```

Expression `subs(p(l,z), z, t)` in function `lk` is used to avoid problems in case if function `RC.p14` don't work with multiple inputs.

This solution will work also if output from `RC.p14` is vector of size n x 1. In this case, function `f1` is derivative of `RC.p14` with same size (n x 1). Output from both subs operation in function lk will have size n x m, where m is size of array t.

Comment: But if @RC.p14 complex function which include function with parameter t. Could be problem that it return vector and RC.p14 will return error or matrix.

Comment: @user1983504 I have add comment in the answer. In addition, function lk should evaluate p using intermediate symbolic function if p don't allow multiple inputs.